# Form action redirect to http//localhost/xampp not to the specified location

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, xampp

I'm new to CodeIgniter. I have a homepage with form controller form. I want when click on submit in homepage redirect to signup function in controller form
But it redirect to `http//localhost//xampp`

**This is Home_view view**

```
<?php $id = 1; ?>
<form action="<?php echo base_url('login_c/signup/' . $id); ?>" method="post" >
  <input type="submit" value="Sign up" />
</form>
```

**This is form controller**

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');

         $this->load->view('Home_view');

    }


     public function signup($id)
    {
        echo$id;
         $this->load->view('myproject/Signup_v');

    }
```

Comment: What is the codeigniter version?? Coz its working fine for me. And also add funn controller.

Comment: What is the file name of your controller??

Comment: form.php  it is redirect to localhost/xampp when i use form action in any file or hyperlink i tried many and display the same result

Comment: Controller file name should start from capital letter. Try running the url directly from browser.

Comment: when i try from browser it work

Comment: The name of the class of controller must start with capital letter but the file name not .also i rename to Form.php and redirect to localhost/xampp

Comment: show the redirect code...

Comment: The code above is the all code

Comment: have you used `.htaccess`??

Comment: This in config.php  $config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/helloworld/"

Comment: Remove base url... Make it as empty...

Comment: I do empty but the same result

Comment: add the `.htaccess` file if you have used it.

Comment: This is .htaccess    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
 
    # Disable rewrite for valid directory/files     
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 
    #map all request urls to a specific controller method
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/{controller}/{method}/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

Comment: I know the answer i write RewriteBase /helloworld instead of RewriteBase /          Thank you for your interest

Answer (score 0):

Yes problem may be with your `.htaccess`. Try with this once,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```